# xamarin forms Android tools options are disabled in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

i'm very new to Xamarin using in Visual Studio 2015 update 3,i'm facing a problem full android tools option has disabled fist few days it was ok but now i recognize it has disabled for debugging i'm using external device only, what is the solution for it. Could you please any one suggest me better to identify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the settings you find here:

[image]

Most likely you need to go to Programs and Change your install for VS 2015 to ensure that you have at least one Android SDK selected.

Comment: could you please provide some more clear about this, which you said

Comment: previous comment i missed to add : "Most likely you need to go to Programs and Change your install for VS 2015 to ensure that you have <b>at least one Android SDK selected</b>."